# The role of TFont.Charset in Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

What is the role of TFont.Charset property of VCL controls in Delphi 2010? Isn't this property irrelevant now that all Delphi 2010 components support UNICODE?

Answer (score 6):

Setting different values for `Charset` property has no effect if a font under question supports these charsets; but if you set a charset not supported by a font Windows will use font substitution to find a font that supports the selected charset. Try to set `SYMBOL_CHARSET` for a text font like Tahoma and see the result.

So though font charsets are legacy in Unicode Delphi's they cannot be ignored completely.